# Using Blender as a video editor can I only add an audio track without recoding a video track?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, audio

The task is to add an additional audio track to a video file (mkv).
But I do not want to change a video track in any way while rendering.
Can it be done in Blender?

Comment: AFAIK no. This isn't something blender is designed to do. You might try using [avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/), or if that doesn't work for you, maybe try asking on [video.se](http://video.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it can't.

Blender only sends its render output to ffmpeg internally which means it's being encoded (again when using decoded footage in the VSE). You can use Blender as a Frameserver as well, but that won't help you out either.

Instead you should use [Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) or [mkvtoolnix](https://mkvtoolnix.download/) to accomplish your goal.

---

**Edit**: As pointed out by [Troy James Sobotka](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/213) in the [comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36708/using-blender-as-a-video-editor-can-i-only-add-an-audio-track-without-recoding-a#comment74345_44209) below, using [FFMPEG](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) directly would be a solution:

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -i audio.mp3 -codec copy -shortest output.avi
```

Comment: While absolutely correct, I'd add FFMPEG to your list of solutions. ffmpeg -i video.avi -i audio.mp3 -codec copy -shortest output.avi. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11783474