# Export VSE edits to Avidemux

Tags: export, video-sequence-editor

After editing some video in blender VSE (just splitting and cutting), I found out I could use Avidemux for direct stream copy which would save me hours of rendering time while keeping the original video quality.
It there a way to save the project editing history into an Avidemux command script, or into any other tool that can do direct stream copy?

Comment: Somehow related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/36708/2843

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "out of the box"-solution for this right now in Blender.

However, you could use some Python scripting to export the cuts. Don't forget, that depending on your Frame distribution (IBP-Frames) and GOP you might not be able to cut frame-precise with Avidemux.

There are some related questions where you can get some help of how to access the frame ranges:

- [How can I drive the Switch nodes True/False value?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/48157/2843)
- [Why is "Copy Data Path" path different from the tooltip's path?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/49123/2843)
- [How to replace an orphaned external file by an existing one? (all instances)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/40411/2843)
- [How to snap the right edge of a strip to the playhead instead of the left in video editor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/47660/2843)

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called Blue Velvet (http://blendervelvets.org/en/blue-velvet/), which exports audiostrips to Ardour.